# How do I encode a csv with OneHotEncoder?

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I'm trying to train an ai to make football results prediction.
But I always got the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2023-09-30T14:00Z'
```

The picture is the csv file containing (Date,Match_Name,Short_Name,Season_Year,Season_Name,Season_Type_Name,Season_Type_Abbreviation,Home,Away,Home_Results,Away_Results) as the column:

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

Here's what I've tried:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn import preprocessing
df = pd.read_csv("fulldata.csv")
x = df.drop(columns=['Home_Results', 'Away_Results'])
y = df['Home_Results']
z = df['Away_Results']
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(x, y)
```

Here's the traceback:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_14808\2162871695.py in ?()
      8 y = df['Home_Results']
      9 z = df['Away_Results']
     10 
     11 model = LogisticRegression()
---> 12 model.fit(x, y)

c:\Users\threa\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in ?(estimator, args, kwargs)
   1148                 skip_parameter_validation=(
   1149                     prefer_skip_nested_validation or global_skip_validation
   1150                 )
   1151             ):
-> 1152                 return fit_method(estimator,args, kwargs)

c:\Users\threa\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model_logistic.py in ?(self, X, y, sample_weight)
   1204             _dtype = np.float64
   1205         else:
   1206             _dtype = [np.float64, np.float32]
   1207 
-> 1208         X, y = self._validate_data(
   1209             X,
   1210             y,
   1211             accept_sparse="csr",
...
   2085         if (
   2086             astype_is_view(values.dtype, arr.dtype)
   2087             and using_copy_on_write()

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2023-09-30T14:00Z'
```

I looked on the internet and I found by encoding the csv with OneHotEncoder, it'll worked. But I've tried with sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoding and pandas.get_dummies, a lot of error showed and I'm out of idea. So here I am to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is your question.
Do you mean,
you got an error `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2023-09-30T14:00Z'` while processing OneHotEncoding or while training a model?

Below is a sample of OneHotEncoding by using both methods.

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
data = df[['Season_Name']]

print('OneHotEncoder------------')
enc = OneHotEncoder()
encoded = enc.fit_transform(data)
print(enc.get_feature_names_out())


print('get_dummies------------')
dummies = pd.get_dummies(data)
print(dummies)
```

I have used dummy data similar to yours.

```
Date,Match_Name,Short_Name,Season_Year,Season_Name
2023-09-30T14:00Z,ManU at vs Cr,CRY @ MAN,2023,2023-24 English Premier League
2023-09-23T19:00Z,ManU at vs Cr,CRY @ MAN,2023,2023-24 UEFA Champions League
2023-09-24T19:00Z,ManU at vs Cr,CRY @ MAN,2023,2023-24 English Premier League
2023-08-21T14:00Z,ManU at vs Cr,CRY @ MAN,2023,2023-24 English Premier League
2023-08-11T21:00Z,ManU at vs Cr,CRY @ MAN,2023,2023 Club Friendly
2023-07-30T14:00Z,ManU at vs Cr,CRY @ MAN,2023,2023-24 English Premier League
2023-07-30T17:00Z,ManU at vs Cr,CRY @ MAN,2023,2023-24 UEFA Champions League
2023-06-30T14:00Z,ManU at vs Cr,CRY @ MAN,2023,2023-24 English Premier League
```

**Note that OneHotEncoding and get_dummies can be applied to the categorical data.** 
I have used Season_Name as one of the examples.

The result will be

```
OneHotEncoder------------
['Season_Name_2023 Club Friendly'
 'Season_Name_2023-24 English Premier League'
 'Season_Name_2023-24 UEFA Champions League']
get_dummies------------
   Season_Name_2023 Club Friendly  Season_Name_2023-24 English Premier League  Season_Name_2023-24 UEFA Champions League
0                           False                                        True                                      False
1                           False                                       False                                       True
2                           False                                        True                                      False
3                           False                                        True                                      False
4                            True                                       False                                      False
5                           False                                        True                                      False
6                           False                                       False                                       True
7                           False                                        True                                      False
```

Keep trying step by step by yourself.
For example, you can make a simpler dataset, and then try to check out the result of OneHotEncoding.

Comment: "*Do you mean, you got an error [...] while processing OneHotEncoding or while training a model?*" - it is apparent from the OP"s code that the issue rises when trying to fit a linear regression model.

Comment: It is when I'm training a model.

Comment: If I encode the data with "Season_Name" or smt else as categorial data, would it affect the training results comparing to when training with the original csv?

Comment: @qing762 No, I don't think so. The encoded data is also the original CSV data itself, but it is just modified to be able to be applied to the model.

Comment: @desertnaut Yeap. Thanks. I'm sorry but, could you let me know the meaning of OP? I'm not familiar with English very well.

Comment: @gwanhun Alright. Thanks for the info.
Btw, op is original poster

Comment: @qing762 The original poster !! Thanks a lot. Enjoy your Machine Learning journey.

Comment: @gwanhun No worries. Thanks a lot!